# Get By.XPath from WebElement used in @Find(how=How.XPATH, using="//a[.='Test']")

Tags: xpath, selenium, web, element

For debugging and reporting purposes, I would like to get the using-part of @Find from a WebElement is this possible? In debug I can go into the WebElement and see its By.XPATH via it's LocatorHandle, so there must be a way to get it during code-time?!
I cannot ofc use the GetAttribute, because I assume the element won't exist, otherwise no need to mention it in the report.

For visualization ;)

```
@FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//a[.='Test']")
private static WebElement btnTest;

public static String GetOrgXpath(WebElement e)
{
    return getByXPath(e); // should return "//a[.='Test']"
}
```

otherwise I would also accept to override WebElement and add a public string to store its xpath, if thats even possible. My Java KungFoo is weak, so dunno how to overwrite Interfaces :)

Thanks for your help

Comment: Just for my understanding: So you have 'WebElement' and you want to know how it was found? BTW, how do you initialize that WebElement?

Comment: i am calling PageFactory.initElements(driver, PageObjects.class); 
it works this way: FindBy annotation = eMB.class.getDeclaredField("tmpTestFail").getAnnotation(FindBy.class); but during runtime i dont have the name of the variable.